# Why cannot git reset to pull request

Tags: git, pull-request

Sometimes I log onto a cloud instance, pull a repo, and then want to try a pull request. The command I use now is

```
git fetch origin pull/<ID>/head && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

which is long. I also tried shorter ways

```
git reset --hard origin/pull/<ID>
git reset --hard origin/pull/<ID>/head
git reset --hard origin/pull/<ID>/HEAD
```

which give the following error

```
$ git reset --hard origin/pull/27
 fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/pull/27': unknown revision
 or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Why does `git reset --hard origin/<some-branch>` work but not the pull request branch?

I notice that in the output of

```
$ git ls-remote origin
```

there is a difference between a regular branch and a pull request branch. For example

> c31a55        refs/heads/fix-async-stdout-order
>
> 615f5a      refs/pull/10/head

How does `heads` differ from `pull`? (I have shorten the hash here so it's visually cleaner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Git repository has its own copies of names.  Each name maps to exactly one hash ID, e.g., in your sample:

> > ```
> > c31a55 refs/heads/fix-async-stdout-order
> > 615f5a refs/pull/10/head
> > ```

you've suggested that `refs/heads/fix-async-stdout-order` maps to hash ID `c31a55`, and `refs/pull/10/head` maps to hash ID `615f5a`.<sup>1</sup>

The *names* are things that Git calls *refs* or *references*.  (The hash IDs are the hashes that you should be quite familiar with by now.)

In most cases, when you give Git a name, Git just immediately turns it into the underlying hash ID.  The hash IDs are what really matter: the names are mainly provided to allow us, mere humans, to deal with the *real* names that are the hash IDs.  The hash IDs never change: they always uniquely identify that particular content—that one specific commit, for instance.  The commit and its hash ID are forever, while one or more names can be created or destroyed at will or whim.<sup>2</sup>

When a name identifies a commit, we can use the name directly to find the commit: `refs/heads/fix-async-stdout-order`, for instance, identifies commit `c31a55`.  But commits also allow us to find their immediate *parent* commits: from `c31a55` we can work backwards to whatever its parent is, and from that parent we can work backwards another step to another commit, and so on, all the way back to the beginning of time in the repository.  So a name like this not only serves to find the one commit whose hash ID it stores, but also *all earlier commits in its chain*.

When the name is a *branch* name—as this one is—Git also allows us to use it specially with `git checkout`.  The `git checkout` command attaches another special name, `HEAD`, to the branch name.  Git now considers us to be "on" the branch, so that if we make *new* commits, Git will *automatically change the hash ID stored under that branch name*.

That is, after:

```
git checkout fix-async-stdout-order
```

if we do some work and then make a *new* commit, the name `fix-async-stdout-order`—which is really `refs/heads/fix-async-stdout-order`, we've just shortened it for display purposes—will stop pointing to commit `c31a55` and start, instead, to point to our new commit.  Our new commit will have `c31a55` as its parent.

This property, of being able to get "on" a branch, is only allowed for *branch* names.  Git has many names: branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on.  All of them are *references*, but only references whose spelling starts with `refs/heads/` are branch names.

The reference `refs/tags/v1.2`, if it exists, is the *tag* named `v1.2`.

The reference `refs/remotes/origin/master`, if it exists, is the *remote-tracking name* `origin/master`.

Each of these prefixes—`refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, and `refs/remotes/`—represents a [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  References in the `refs/heads/` namespace are *branch names*.

Besides being special in terms of allowing `git checkout` to use them in the way described above, the other special feature of a *branch* name occurs when a client Git—such as your own Git—connects to a server Git.  The server Git displays, for the client, all of its names, including the branch names, along with the hash IDs that those names represent.  The *client* Git *copies down* the server's *branch* names but *changes* them at the same time, so that what the server calls `refs/heads/master`, the client calls `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

This process is how *your* Git comes to have remote-tracking names in the first place.  The server Git has its branches, and your Git comes along—when you run `git fetch`—and sees and then *remembers* their branches as your remote-tracking `origin/*` names.  These live in your Git, in the `refs/remotes/` namespace.

This process occurs *only* for branch names!<sup>3</sup>  Since `refs/pull/10/head` does not start with `refs/heads/`, it is not a branch name.  The process does not apply to `refs/pull/10/head`.  So that's why and how `heads` differs from `pull`.

---

<sup>1</sup>These are both *abbreviated* hash IDs; actual hash IDs are currently always 40 characters long.

<sup>2</sup>The caveat here is that without a name that allows you to *find* a commit, or other Git object, that commit or other object is now *unprotected* from Git's garbage collection process.  So not only do names allow us to find the *last* commit in a chain, they also protect that commit *and* all of its predecessors from being taken out as trash.

<sup>3</sup>The process is programmable, through what Git calls *refspecs*.  The description above applies only to the *default* refspecs that you get when you run `git clone`.  If you make up your own refspecs, you can change what happens here.  See [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.html) and note that `remote.origin.fetch` is a *cumulative* setting; each instance of `remote.origin.fetch` provides one refspec.

The default at clone time is for Git to create one `remote.origin.fetch` setting, that either copies *all* of their branches to your remote-tracking names, or copies *one* of their branches to *one* remote-tracking name if you opted for `--single-branch` during cloning.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub suggests](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally): `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME`: that way you are controlling the local branch naming convention, instead of creating (due to the default refspec on GitHub for PR)

But you have [more advance techniques here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201407/fetching_github_pull_requests.html):

```
[alias]
copr = "!f() { git fetch -fu ${2:-origin} refs/pull/$1/head:pr/$1 &&
                    git checkout pr/$1; }; f"
```

And then:

```
$ git copr 1234            # gets and switches to pr/1234 from origin
$ git copr 789 upstream    # gets and switches to pr/789 from upstream
```

**[hub](https://hub.github.com/)** is also known for wrapping the PR import.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually know alias. I just wonder what makes the pull request branch different from a regular one

Comment: @nos the way GitHub references its PR: `refs/pull/*`. Without any local refspec on your side, that refspec is replicated by your fetch.