# How do I make sure I have the latest version of my develop branch?

Tags: git, version-control

Here is a schematic of our codebase:

Master Branch (off limits)

Develop Branch (where team works from) ----> Feature Branches(created from develop branch to work on individual features)

So when I am working on a feature I make a local branch with the ticket number and feature name. So let's say I want to make sure that my local feature branch is up to date with the develop branch when I start working every day. There is already a copy of my feature branch in the remote repo (from a previous pull request). Should I just do a "git pull"? Since the remote feature branch is in the same remote repo as the develop branch (where the whole team pushes their approved changes). Will I get the latest version of the develop branch to work with locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So let's say I want to make sure that my local feature branch is up to date with the develop branch when I start working every day

You need to fetch the remote branches (including develop) first:

```
git fetch
```

Then you can rebase your feature branch on top of it:

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

That is good for short-lived local feature branch, before pushing it for the first time.

But replaying your commits over and over is not always practical in the long run, especially if you need to regularly push your feature branch (for integration testing, or for collaboration with others): that push would be a force push (`git push --force`).

If you need to push often your feature branch, then fetch+merge is easier:

```
git merge origin/develop
```

You can do such a merge from time to time (no need to do it necessarily every morning). It depends when you want to take time and integrate your current work in progress with the latest develop codebase state.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I guess my main question now is, if I am in my local feature branch and do a git pull, what am I actually getting from the remote repo? Am I only getting my remote copy of my feature branch? Or am I getting the latest version of the remote develop branch?

Comment: @frootloops Do a `git branch -avv`: if your feature branch was pushed once, what a `git push` will give you (with the default refspec: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) will be just itself, merged with `origin/feature`. That is why I recommend `git fetch`: it fetches all the branches by default( (in the `origin` namespace). You can then rebase or merge what you need into your local feature branch.

Comment: @frootloops For more on refspecs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997659/6309

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. I asked, "if I am in my local feature branch and do a git pull, what am I actually getting from the remote repo?" In the comment you mention a git push and link. I'm sorry I don't quite understand the answer. I am just curious what a git pull will do. Am I going to receive the latest version of the develop branch merged in with my local feature branch? I know a git pull is the combination of fetch and merge. I am just not sure what I am fetching.

Comment: @frootloops a `git pull` does by default a fetch + merge of *your* branch: you get the remote branches, and, out of those remote branches, you are merging `origin/feature` to your `feature` branch. But what you need is merging `origin/develop` to your `feature` branch, in order to update it with the latest of the `develop` commits. Hence my answer.

Comment: @frootloops With pictures: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull illustrates what a `git pull` does.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion.